# Errors NotRegistered flask-mongoengine Tutorial

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I started this Turial, [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/)

And get this error

```
**mongoengine.errors.NotRegistered:** `Comment` has not been registered in the document registry. Importing the document class automatically registers it, has it been imported?
```

any idea.
Thank you So much.

Answer (score 4):

First register all your models some where like `__init__.py` file in your `models` package.

Then you can use `get_document('Comment')` function (which is imported from `mongoengine.base.common`) instead of importing your models in each other scripts to avoid circular imports and exceptions like `mongoengine.errors.NotRegistered`

Comment: could you provide an example using multiple files?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, @Hamid please provide an example with circular import.

Answer (score 3):

Just place the Comment Model above the Post Model, since the Comment Model is being referenced in the Post Model